# Characters not displaying correctly in different browsers

Tags: html

I used certain characters in website such as `• — “ ” ‘ ’ º ©`.
I found that when testing to see what my website looked like under different browsers ([BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html))
the afore-mentioned characters are replaced with `ï¿½`.

I then changed the charset in the webpage header from:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Suddenly all the pages have the above mentioned characters replaced with a `?`.

Even more puzzling is this is not always consistent across and even within the same page, as some sections display the character `•` and `©` correctly.

In particular, I need to replace the character `•` with one that will display across browsers, can anyone help me with the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Unicode encodings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save your HTML source as UTF8.

Alternatively, you can use HTML entities instead.

Comment: I am going through the pages and replacing with the HTML entities as suggested. It seems to renders correctly under different browsers. I will need to remember to do replacement of HTML entities in my other subweb sections before I change the charset to utf-8. Not sure if I need to replace © with &copy; in my <meta name="copyright" content="2001-2012 © Company Pty Ltd">

Answer (score 1):

The source code needs to be saved in the same encoding as you're instructing the browser to parse it in. If you're saving your files in UTF-8, instruct the browser to parse it as UTF-8 by setting an appropriate HTTP header or HTML meta tag (headers preferable, your web server may be setting one without you knowing). Use a decent editor that clearly tells you what encoding you're saving the file as. If it doesn't display correctly, there's a discrepancy between what you're telling your browser the file is encoded in and what it's really encoded in.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Apache is setup to send the charset.  Look for the directive "AddDefaultCharset" and set it to Off in .htaccess or your config file.

Most/all browsers will take what is sent in the HTTP headers over what is in the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Notepad++, I suggest You to use Edit Plus editor to copy the text (which has the special characters) and paste it in your file. This should work.

Answer (score -2):

Yes I had this problem too in notepad++ copy and pasting wasn't working with some symbols

I think SLaks is right

HTML entities for copyright symbol   &#169